# How to develop a notifier type Android application

Tags: android

I am starting to develop Android applications. I've read several tutorials and already made a small useless (but beyond hello world) application.

I know how I should go about creating a regular application, but that's not what I want to do.

I want to build a "notifier type" application. Think about a "gmail notifier" app, only not for Gmail, but for another web service. I can handle the web service and everything.

What I don't know is how to go about building the application, because it doesn't have a UI (Well, only an options page), and it needs to be running in the background all the time checking for updates at defined intervals (changeable from the options page).

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use a Service, you can read all about services here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
2. I'm not sure if u are forced or not to have an Activity, but in any case if you are you can do the settings in that Activity, just make sure the action for Main and category Launcher will not be in this Activity, unless that's what you want (that every time u click the app icon you will get the settings screen).
3. if you want your Service to start on start up listen to
   < intent-filter>
      < action android:name ="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   < /intent-filter>

good luck :-)

Comment: thank you so much!
(that every time u click the app icon you will get the settings screen) - i think that is what i want. what do you think?

Comment: what i think is not really relevant :-) it's not my app... but it sounds reasonable to have a service that when you click it's icon you get the preferences if no other visible parts are available, just like i like it, no bullshit, all strait up...